# ldapsearch get no entry err 32(openldap)

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I got no response when I do ldapsearch like this.

```
> ldapsearch -x -D "uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -w joe -b "ou=group,dc=example,dc=org" "(objectclass=*)"

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=group,dc=example,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

Openldap log is here

```
5c10a31c conn=1029 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=172.17.0.1:34710 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
5c10a31c conn=1029 op=0 BIND dn="uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org"     method=128
5c10a31c conn=1029 op=0 BIND dn="uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
5c10a31c conn=1029 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
5c10a31c conn=1029 op=1 SRCH base="ou=group,dc=example,dc=org" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
5c10a31c conn=1029 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
5c10a31c conn=1029 op=2 UNBIND
5c10a31c conn=1029 fd=13 closed
```

this is ldif file for user and group

```
# People, example.org
dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
ou: people
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# Groups, example.org
dn: ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
ou: group
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: joe
cn: Joe Doe
sn: Doe
givenName: Joe
userPassword: joe
description: This is an example user

dn: cn=c3admin,ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: c3admin
member: uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
```

It seems like binding user and base dn are not correctly setup.
Please give me a advise for solving this problem.

I am using osixia/docker-openldap:1.2.2 for the openldap. and it has auto setting for admin user at "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org"

*docker run -p 389:389 -p 689:689 --name my-openldap-container --detach osixia/openldap:1.2.2*

## Update

Do search with member filter then got the error.

```
ldapsearch -x -D "uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -w joe -b "ou=group,dc=example,dc=org" "(member=uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org)"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=group,dc=example,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (member=uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

Do search with base DN then got the error.

```
ldapsearch -x -D "uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -w joe -b "dc=example,dc=org" "(objectclass=*)"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

Do search with binding admin dn, then got the 5 entries.
    ldapsearch -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w admin -b "ou=group,dc=example,dc=org" "(objectclass=*)"
    # extended LDIF
    #
    # LDAPv3
    # base  with scope subtree
    # filter: (objectclass=*)
    # requesting: ALL
    #

```
# group, example.org
dn: ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
ou: group
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# admin, group, example.org
dn: cn=admin,ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
cn: admin
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: uid=john,ou=group,dc=example,dc=org

# john, group, example.org
dn: uid=john,ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
uid: john
givenName: Joe
description: This is an example user
sn: Doe
cn: Joe Doe
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
userPassword:: am9obg==

# c3admin, group, example.org
dn: cn=c3admin,ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: c3admin
member: uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org

# c3viewer, group, example.org
dn: cn=c3viewer,ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: c3viewer
member: uid=tom,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 6
# numEntries: 5
```

Comment: Update the content follow @jwilleke's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your search is asking to return the entries "(objectclass=*)" below the entry "ou=group,dc=example,dc=org".

I am guessing there are none.

To find the members which are within the group ou=group,dc=example,dc=org, use a filter similar to:
"(member=*)"

to find all the entries use: 
Filter:  "(objectclass=*)"
Base (-b): "dc=example,dc=org"

-jim

Comment: Hello jwilleke, I update the result as what you suggest, it has the same result. It looks like Binding Dn and base DN  problem. I could not find the solution yet.

Comment: Then either: uid=joe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org or ou=group,dc=example,dc=org is wrong. I would suggest you get a LDAP Browser like: https://directory.apache.org/studio/ .

Comment: I am using Apache Directory Studio, Connection bind DN is cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org. I try to search base group OU with binding one of people OU. because I use Jetty server JAAS and it acts like that way.